# My guide NPC isn't spawning

Tags: terraria

It's been 14 in-game days and he hasn't re-spawned. I died at the Wall of Flesh and I don't get the debuff when I go into Hell so the WoF isn't the problem.  I checked all the skylands, my old houses, and the default spawn point; I went the East and West ends.  There isn't a goblin invasion going on.  So I'm clueless as to what's happening.  I just want to get into Hardmode, but I can't because the dang Guide isn't spawning.

The house I made for him is suitable. 2 doors, 2 torches, table, chair, walls 6 high 10 wide.  I've been standing at the East end of the map for him to spawn, but nope. Any suggestions on what I need to/can do for this bug would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you already tried save & exit, then reload your game? Sometimes that's helped my guide spawn.

Comment: Copy of http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/81025/why-arent-my-guide-and-other-dead-npcs-respawning-in-terraria?

Answer (score 1):

**The Guide will only spawn if:**

- It's daytime.
- There is an available house.
- No invasion/Eclipse is happening.
- It is also possible for another npc to take over the same house you want your guide in, after he died.
- Your house isn't too close to corruption or crimson.

Check to see if all these requirements are met, and check if your house is suitable (with the check housing button). Make multiple extra houses.

Many players report a bug, that the guide doesn't spawn until roughly a day or more (in real time) after you die to the WoF. This could very likely be it, but make sure you follow through all the steps listed here cause it could also not be the bug.

Comment: Everything listen above i have checked and done, The guide isn't spawning. at all... It's getting annoying actually. Any furter more information you have?

Comment: @Jess Afk, wait it out. It's a bug that hasn't been fixed for a while.

Comment: The post was edited, does the new (last) point help you?

Answer (score 1):

When I played this I had it happen to me, the way I fixed it was I had to search the entire map to find any goblins left of a goblin invasion and kill them off. When the entire invasion has been killed, you should get text saying invasion defeated and the guide should spawn if this is what it causing him not to spawn.