# Why does any NPC besides the guide move into the houses I built?

Tags: terraria

I have 3 houses which appear to all be the same. When I built the first house, the merchant moved into it instead of the guide. The guide is currently dead.
Each time I build a new house, an NPC other than the guide moves into it. I'm using mods on my game.

Comment: If you want to know whether or not guides can move into houses, you should reword the title. Otherwise, asking *why* a game mechanic is the way it is is off-topic and will be closed as such.

Answer (score 5):

Simply build more houses and your Guide will eventually respawn. The game prioritizes spawning new NPCs rather than respawning dead ones, so there's nothing else you can do.

Comment: um.... really? Thanks but is there any other way?

Comment: The Guide will only spawn if: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/190293/147140

Comment: @Paul Which is the same as any other NPC.

Answer (score 0):

Just be patient and wait for him to respawn in the meantime  Adventure and fight  bosses create stuff  do all sorts of fun stuff in terraria  until he respawns

Comment: I have a modded survival and want to know the recipes from modded items. Since the mods don't have quite good wiki's, I have to find out using guide